# Hibernate nested embedded primary keys or flat fields?

Tags: java, hibernate, nested, primary-key, composite-key

I have two classes with nested composite primary-keys (composite PK of `B` includes composite PK of `A`)

```
class A {
    @EmbeddedId
    APk aId;
}

@Embeddable
class APk {
    @Column
    Long x;
    @Column
    Long y;
}

class B {
    @EmbeddedId
    BPk bId;
}
```

Knowing that composite primary-keys in hibernate are not recommended: what is the recommended way to implement the primary key type for `B`?

Alternative 1 - with the PK of A embedded?

Alternative 2 - or with all 3 properties declared in a more flat implementation?

```
@Embeddable
class BPk {
    // Alternative 1
    @Embedded
    APk aId;
    @Column
    Long z;
}


@Embeddable
class BPk {
   // Alternative 2
    @Column
    Long x;
    @Column
    Long y;
    @Column
    Long z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference between these two alternatives. You will be able to override the mapping of the properties in both cases, if needed. If APk is reused more than once, alternative 1 would be better. Otherwise, keep it simple with alternative 2.

Comment: I was looking for some major advantage in either case; basically the only difference I can remember is the ability to use [`@MapsId`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id) annotation in `B` class when mapping `A` relation